"permission denied" error when running cross-site query
When attempting to run a cross-site SEDE query, I get this:
Line 1: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'tempdb'.

I can reproduce this with the provided examples.
While I realize it's around the holidays, could someone take a look at this at some point?

It looks like this issue has been resolved. Our permissions are reinstated.
